# CSS, JavaScript, HTML, how can i align a text inside a div to middle beside an image? and animate the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm new to html and im trying to make a simple webpage.

i'm having a problem aligning the text to middle beside its image.

how can i also make an animation where when i click the image, the text beside of it will slide to left under the image. meaning the text will hide under the image. (an animation where the text slide to the left sequential per letter. first letter then next letter and so on... with fast animation.)

and when i click the image again. it will show the text in the same manner.

HTML:

```
    <div class="containerout">  
    <div class="containerin">

    <div class="containerinner">
         <img id="sprite" src="http://www.coderworkshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/CompletedBlueGuy.png" width="35px" height="auto" alt="sprite pic" /><span>LONGER LONGER TEXT</span>
    </div>

    <div class="containerinner">
         <img id="sprite" src="http://www.coderworkshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/CompletedBlueGuy.png" width="35px" height="auto" alt="sprite pic" /><span>LONGGERR TEXT</span>
    </div>

    <div class="containerinner">
         <img id="sprite" src="http://www.coderworkshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/CompletedBlueGuy.png" width="35px" height="auto" alt="sprite pic" /><span>SHORTER TEXT</span>
    </div>

    </div>  
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.containerinner {
    height: 35px ;
    border: 2px solid black ;
    padding: 4.5px ;
    margin: 5% auto ;
    width: auto ;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/backspaced/LfhLovd7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, about aligning the text to the middle of the image, add this to your CSS:

```
.containerinner img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And as far as the animation goes, maybe something like the following?

```
$("img").click(function () {
   $("span").animate({
       width: 'toggle'
   }, 500);
});
```

With some additional CSS to keep the text on a single line:

```
span {
    height: 18px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lemoncurry/wj2nrwo8/

Comment: how can i also make the border wrap the white space? (the width of the border should automatically expand/condense depending on the text's width)

Comment: Try adding the following to the CSS for .containerinner: display: inline-block;

Comment: wow. .animate is jquery right? and about the width of the border, can it be part of the animation? not just the text?

Comment: Yes, .animate is jQuery. You can animate pretty much anything. Have fun, but keep in mind that with great power comes great responsibility ;)

Comment: display: inline-block : works but makes the div's align in 1 line.

Comment: You can put a line-break between the divs in the HTML: <br />.